# Spring Boot 3.0 + Security 6 +WebFlux causes "An expected CSRF token cannot be found" in Postman

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

The following **SecurityWebFilterChain** works very fine in Spring Boot 2.7.x but not working any more in Spring Boot 3.0.0. It just show "**An expected CSRF token cannot be found**" when calling the REST API in Postman. Would you please to teach me how to solve it?

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securitygWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    
    
    http
            .cors().disable()               
            .csrf().disable()
            
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint((swe, e) -> 
                Mono.fromRunnable(() -> swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
            ).accessDeniedHandler((swe, e) -> 
                Mono.fromRunnable(() -> swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN))
            )
            .and()
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
            .authorizeExchange(exchange -> exchange                                     
                    .pathMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
                    .pathMatchers("/login", "/register").permitAll()                        
                    .anyExchange().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .cors().disable()
                    .csrf().disable()
            )
            .formLogin().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()   
            ;
            
    return http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()).build();
}
```

[image: Postman screen capture]

Comment: Are you sure that this `SecurityWebFilterChain` is being picked up and not another one?

Comment: how can i know if the SecurityWebFilterChsin is being picked up?

Comment: I have the same problem today.. I upgraded my webflux REST API project from springboot version `2.7.x` to `3.0.0` and getting same error even with `http.csrf().disable()` this works fine in springboot `2.7.x`. I can't find any documentation on if anything is being changed in `SecurityWebFilterChain`

Answer (score 12):

I experienced the same symptoms when migrating my webflux application to Spring Boot 3.0.0 today, which worked perfectly with 2.7.5. So I googled for "csrf-disabling no longer working" and found this and some few other posts...

However in my case, it was an annotation change of Spring security 6, that caused the problem: @EnableWebFluxSecurity contained "@Configuration" in 5.x version (I checked) - but obviously does no longer and has to be added explicitly.

Thus the complete SecurityWebFilterChain bean was not found after migrating... Now the working code looks as follows:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@Configuration       // <- this was integrated in @EnableWebFluxSecurity with Spring Security 5.x
public class AccountWebSecurityConfig { 

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http,  
                                                            ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                                                            ServerAccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler,
                                                            ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint) {
    http.csrf().disable()
        .httpBasic(httpBasicSpec -> httpBasicSpec
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                // when moving next line to exceptionHandlingSpecs, get empty body 401 for authentication failures (e.g. Invalid Credentials)
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
        )
        .authorizeExchange()
        //...
}
```

As your FilterChain - snippet does not show the annotations at your class, chances are, you may also missing the @Configuration

In my case now everything works as before :-)

Comment: I'm currently experiencing the same issue. 
I have added `@Configuration and @EnableWebFluxSecurity` annotations and yet it is not still working for me, I'm currently using spring boot 3.0.4 and webflux

I feel it is a bug or something

Answer (score 0):

> You can try it out

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html

> application.yml

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://idp.example.com/issuer
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to enable resource-server in your filter-chain:

```java
http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter)
```

You need a custom authentication converter, as done above, mostly for roles mapping.

Detailed tutorials (for servlets) here: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials. You might then refer to [samples](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples) for reactive apps.